# where to keep the file path while hosting the java web app?

Tags: java, glassfish

I have developed a website, one of its operation is to read and write data to text files stored at my local machine such as D://test.txt or C://file.txt, but now I am going to host my website at the external server, i mean over the internet use, i wonder where to keep these files that are associated with read and writing operations. At present I am getting an exception file not found if i am using my local machine location. For your information, I am using GlassFish server.

Comment: You need to keep in the same server where you app is deployed. Exact C or D drive depends completely on your hosting provider, they are the best point of contact to get this information.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep i will try it out now..

Comment: Thanks Pradeep its done....cheers

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a system property on Glassfish, which represents the file path and name. Then upload the file to that location of your choosing on the server where your website application is deployed.

Depending upon your needs, you may find it easier to deploy the file out with your application. Make sure the file is on the classpath, and you can load it using any number of ways.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how to create a system property on glassfish, I am unable to understand this part. I am new to this, help please...

Comment: I don't use Glassfish so I don't know, but a Google search turns up this as the first result: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ghcjc.html